# Database design dilemma

Tags: database-design

I am building a fleet unit management software which handles data from GPS devices mounted on the clients' vehicles.

Now I have to implement the database design. I have two main tables.

- Table 1: `Fleet_Unit` (unit_id, col_2, col_3, col_4), `unit_id` is PK
- Table 2: `Gps_Device` (device_id, col_2, col_3, col_4), `device_id` is PK

In most scenarios, only one gps device is mounted on one vehicle but there are cases when two or even more gps devices may be mounted on the same vehicle for various reasons. So I have to decide if I should have an extra table to map the vehicles to the gps devices or put an extra column inside the `Gps_Device` table where the ID of the `Fleet_Unit` table will be stored.

I decided to use the first approach so I created one more table:

- `Fleet_unit_gps_device_mapping` (fleet_unit_id, gps_device_id)

So before I ask you for opinion let me introduce you few more tables that are used to describe the fleet_unit object.

Each gps device has some analog and digital I/O. There may be one or more fuel meters connected to the gps device and vehicle's engine, temp sensors, card readers and so on.

So here is ONE of the extra tables (the others are similar):

- `fleet_unit_digital_sensors_mapping` (fleet_unit_id, gps_device_id, sensor_col_1, sensor_col_2)

As I mentioned there may be more than one gps device mounted on the same vehicle so ***digital-sensor-1*** which is read from *first gps device* is different from **digital-sensor-1** which is read from the *second gps device*.

Now I'd like to ask you how to implement the database.

Should I use `fleet_unit_id` and `gps_device_id` from table `fleet_unit_digital_sensors_mapping` as foreign keys for tables `Fleet_Unit` and `Gps_Device`

or

Should I create a new column `master_id` which is a "combination" of `fleet_unit_id` and `gps_device_id` and connect it to the mapping table - `Fleet_unit_gps_device_mapping` where I need to introduce another column used for the map.

The reason I'm asking is because in first scenario if I have 10+ tables that describe the vehicle I have to connect each one with the `fleet_unit` and `gps_device` table. In second case I simply connect all 10+ tables with the table that maps the vehicle and the gps devices.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am I correct to assume that at any given point in time, each `gps_device` can only be in **one** `fleet_unit`? In that case, your extra m:n mapping table really isn't needed, just include `unit_id` as a FK in your `gps_device` table - seems a lot simpler

Comment: Yes, you are right.